# How can an Operating System be coded in high level languages?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, computer-science, cpu-architecture, virtual-memory

I just started diving into the world of operating systems and I've learned that processes have a certain memory space they can address which is handled by the operating system. I don't quite understand how can an Operating System written in high level languages like c and c++ obtain this kind of memory management functionality.

Answer (score 3):

You have caught the bug and there is no cure for it :-)

The language you use to write your OS has very little to do with the way your OS operates.  Yes, most people use C/C++, but there are others.  As for the language, you do need a language that will let you directly communicate with the hardware you plan to manage, assembly being the main choice for this part.  However, this is less than 5% of the whole project.

The code that you write must not rely upon any existing operating system.  i.e.: you must code all of the function yourself, or call existing libraries.  However, these existing libraries must be written so that they don't rely upon anything else.

Once you have a base, you can write your OS in any language you choose, with the minor part in assembly, something a high level language won't allow.  In fact, in 64-bit code, some compilers no longer allow inline assembly, so this makes that 5% I mentioned above more like 15%.

Find out what you would like to do and then find out if that can be done in the language of choice.  For example, the main operating system components can be written in C, while the actual processor management (interrupts, etc) must be done in assembly.  Your boot code must be in assembly as well, at least most of it.

As [mentioned in a different post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59594310/12381289), I have some [early example code](https://github.com/fysnet/FYSOS) that you might want to look at.  The boot is done in assembly, while the loader code, both Legacy BIOS and EFI, are mostly C code.

Comment: I was going to say "does anyone really use MSVC to write kernels?", but I guess Microsoft does for Windows itself.  Turns out they have an [intrinsic for `invlpg`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/invlpg?view=vs-2019), and presumably other privileged instructions.  So they don't need to make inefficient call to stand-alone functions to work around the fact that their compiler's inline-asm internal implementation was so hacky it only worked for 32-bit x86.

Answer (score 2):

To clarify fysnet's answer, the reason you have to use at least a bit of assembly is that you can only explicitly access addressable memory in C/C++ (through pointers), while hardware registers (such as the program counter or stack pointer) often don't have memory addresses. Not only that, but some registers have to be manipulated with CPU architecture-dependent special instructions, and that, too, is only possible in machine language.

> I don't quite understand how can an Operating System written in high level languages like c and c++ obtain this kind of memory management functionality.

As described above, depending on the architecture, this could be achieved by having special instructions to manage the MMU, TLB etc. [INVLPG](https://x86.puri.sm/html/file_module_x86_id_144.html) is one example of such an instruction in the x86 architecture. Note that having a special instruction requiring kernel privileges is probably the simplest way to implement such a feature in hardware in a secure manner, because then it is simply sufficient to check if the CPU is in kernel mode in order to determine whether the instruction can be executed or not.

Answer (score 1):

Compilers turn high-level languages into asm / machine code for you, so you don't have to write asm yourself.  You pick a compiler that handles memory the way you want your OS to; e.g. using the callstack for automatic storage, and not implicitly calling `malloc` / `free` (because those won't exist in your kernel).

To link your compiled C/C++ into a kernel, you typically have to know more about the ABI it targets, and the toolchain especially the linker.

The ISO C standard treats implementation details very much as a black box.  But real compilers that people use for low level stuff work in well-known ways (i.e. make the expected/useful implementation choices) that kernel programmers depend on, in terms of compiling code and static data into contiguous blocks that can be linked into a single kernel executable that can be loaded all as one chunk.

---

As for actually managing the system's memory, you write code yourself to do that, with a bit of inline asm where necessary for special instructions like `invlpg` as other answers mention.

**The entry point (where execution starts) will normally be written in pure asm**, to set up a callstack with the stack pointer register pointing to it. 
 And set up virtual memory and so on so code is executable, data is read/write, and read-only data is readable.   All of this before jumping to any compiled C code.  The first C you jump to is probably more kernel init code, e.g. initializing data structures for an allocator to manage all the memory that isn't already in use by static code/data.

Creating a stack and mapping code/data into memory is the kind of setup that's normally done *by* an OS when starting a user-space program.  The asm emitted by a compiler will assume that code, static data, and the stack are all there already.